# How to access Remote Desktop from Android 2.1?

Tags: remote-access

Suppose I am developing my application in WPF, for windows 2008 R2, and the tablet will be running Android in a LAN with Wi-Fi, and I would like to try to use the existing .net technology via RDP on the Android Emulator.

How to install Remote Desktop Client on Android 2.1?

Comment: Why did someone click to close? The question is pertinent and important. If there is not solution for using RDP in Android I will not be able to use it for a urgent project.

Comment: Using the RDP on Android is related to programming platform.

Comment: I had no idea what you're trying to do, try editing your question so it is less vague. In particular, are you using a Windows machine to connect to an Android tablet are are you using Android to connect to a Windows machine? And how does WPF comes into play within this?

Comment: I plan to use a Android 2.1 Tablet + wifi with Remote Desktop to access a WPF application running on a Windows computer.

Answer (score 2):

Try [PocketCloud](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.wyse.pocketcloudfree&hl=en) on the Android Market. It's free for one PC connection.

Comment: Thank you for point this application. I will try a solution in the android market website.

Answer (score 1):

Search the Market for Remote Desktop.

I use "Remote Desktop Enterprise".

Answer (score 1):

[Xtralogic](http://www.xtralogic.com/rdpclient.shtml) has a RDP client for Android.

There's also [Omnidesk's](http://andappstore.com/AndroidApplications/apps/Omnidesk_v2) free app.

And there's [Remote](http://www.remotespark.com/android.html).

If necessary there are implementations of [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) for Android, and no doubt there's VNC apps.